# unable to create recs via foreign key association in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am completely new to django and python need your insights here

I am trying to parse a list of csv files from a directory,
storing the name and row_count in Files model and the content of the csv in Work model(associated with Files)

I have two queries

The recs are created in Files model , but no recs being created in Work model, below is my code and no error message is thrown

Models

```
class Files(models.Model):
    filename   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    work_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Work(models.Model):
    proprietary_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    iswc           = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    source         = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    title          = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    contributors   = JSONField()
    file           = models.ForeignKey(Files,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

View

```
root_dir="D:/Django/siva/files"
for file in os.listdir(root_dir):
   with open(f'{root_dir}/{file}','r') as csv_file:
       csv_reader= csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
       Files.objects.create(filename=file, work_count=len(list(csv_reader)))
       for row in csv_reader:
           file_obj=Files.objects.get(filename=file)
           print(file_obj)
           Work.objects.create(proprietary_id=row['proprietary_id'],iswc=row['iswc'],source=row['source'],title=row['title'],contributors=row['contributors'],file_=file_obj)
```

sample csv file

```
title,contributors,iswc,source,proprietary_id
Shape of You,Edward Christopher Sheeran,T9204649558,sony,1
Je ne sais pas,Obispo Pascal Michel|Florence Lionel Jacques,T0046951705,sony,3
```

And also is there any specific method to set the root_dir  , so I don't need to change the filepath structure across OS's

Comment: Is the `print(file_obj)` printing the file instance for every row?

Comment: yes getting the objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `DictReader` instance is already consumed by the time you get to `for row in csv_reader:`. When it is converted to a list in order to retrieve the length the whole generator is consumed and nothing is left for the forloop.

You can fix this just by converting the object to a list or tuple immediately after creating it.

```py
csv_reader = tuple(csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=','))
```

This will raise another error where `file_=file_obj` should actually be `file=file_obj`, but that's a very easy fix.

For your path problem: assuming you're Django install is a fairly recent one you should be able to just import your settings and access `settings.BASE_DIR`

```py
from django.conf import settings

settings.BASE_DIR
```

This is a [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object and should be very useful to you. It will allow you to access your files in a much more natural way.

Here's how I would go about writing this chunk of code.

```py
root = settings.BASE_DIR / '../path/to/csv'
for path in root.iterdir():
    with path.open('r') as source:
        data = tuple(csv.DictReader(source, delimiter=','))

    file_ = Files.objects.create(filename=path.name, work_count=len(data))
    Work.objects.bulk_create([Work(file=file_, **kwargs) for kwargs in data])
```